# Kubuntu: how to change system language, thus not only users language

Tags: language-support

I've change my language from English to Dutch, but that only affects my account. How to change the language system wide. Please, tel me for Kubuntu, not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit `/etc/default/locale`. That file probably has this line:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Change it to:

```
LANG=nl_NL.UTF-8
```